# Best way to check if variable exists before subtraction?

Tags: php, subtraction

I have a variable, for example $total1. It has a value from the database, for example 6.

Now I do an SQL query and it gets some numbers from tables. For example this:
$subtraction1=5, but it is in a while loop so the second time it could be $subtraction1=10 or something like that. Every time in the while loop the $subtraction_total variable would be $subtraction_total1+$subtraction1, because at the bottom of the page I would like to show the $total minus the $subtraction_total1.

But the first time in the while loop I must check if $subtraction_total already exists. I know to options to do that, but is there a shorter way?

Option 1 is to define the variable $subtraction_total1 before the while loop.

Option 2 is to do this:

```
(!isset($total_subtraction1)){$total_subtraction1=0;}$total_subtraction1=$total1-$subtraction1;
```

Now you think: well, just do option 1: define 1 variable, but it is for around 15 variables and I was just wondering if there is a shorter way;-)

Hope you understand me, my English is not very good;-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Define** and initialize all your variables **before use**. I think Option 1 follows logically from that.

Don't try to write code that is short, or fast or tricky. Write code that is easy to read and maintain.

Comment: I suppose it's good to find equilibrium between code that's readable/maintainable and code that's short and concise :P

Answer (score 2):

I would definitely advocate defining the variable(s) before the loop. Repeatedly calling `isset` (or any other function) over and over inside a loop is wasteful if the same functionality can be achieved pre-loop.

If you're simply looking to define a large number of variables without having to explicitly declare each one before your loop you might try [`list`<sup>*docs*</sup>](http://php.net/manual/en/function.list.php) or programmatically create your variables in a loop.

Answer (score 1):

```
$sub_total = 0;
while ($sub = mysql_get_row(...)) {
  $sub_total += $sub;
}
```

This way you don't execute the same code again in every iteration (which is good practice and good performance wise), and it has the added advantage that if you have no result from mysql, $sub_total is defined with a default value.